# Rails associations / sessions question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I am working on a app for my kids to log their chores.  I have 3 children (Nick, Siena, Mac) and have a home page with each name hyperlinked ...

I have the following associations:

```
Child:
  has_many :completions
  has_many :chores, :through=>:completion

Completion: 
  belongs_to :child
  belongs_to :chore

Chore:
  has_many :completions
  has_many :kid, :through=>:completion
```

1. How do I (upon clicking the child's name) save the child_id as a session object for posting completions to the completions models?
2. How do I clear / change that sesison to a new child when another child clicks their name in the homepage?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks, CB

Comment: How does Rails routing relate to your question ? :/

Comment: Is there a question here? It certainly doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Hopefully i cleaned up the question.  I need to pass the child_id along to the next view (chores/index)... so that upon selecting the chores and clicking submit.. the child_id and chore_id are passed to the completed model.  many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly (at least as described in your comment), I did something similar recently.  See [Building a nested attribute from multiple parent objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617264/building-a-nested-attribute-from-multiple-parent-objects). Basically, I used polymorphic_url to make a link to create a new item (I would probably use @child.chores.build(params)) and pass the attribute :chore_id, i.e.

```
link_to "Mark as complete", polymorphic_url([:new, @child, :completion], :chore_id => @chore.id)
```

In your controller make sure that for your ChoresController#new you have something like

```
def new
  @chore = <current_child>.chores.build(params)
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate it.  I think I am asking something even more simple... How do I set "current child" upon clicking the child's name?

Comment: Are you talking as more of a global variable?  Or will this be in the context of a certain model?

Answer (score 1):

So josh went above and beyond.  As a noob i was asking something much more simple and elementary for most folks.  The answer was quite simple:

```
ApplicationController

private
  def current_child
    child = Child.find(params[:id])
    session[:child_id] = child.id
  end
end
```

This allowed me to store that child's id in a session and post to the completed model.

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  Your solution was going to be along the lines of my next suggestion.  Glad that's working for you.

Comment: Thanks to you as well Josh.  Looks like you are a great help/resource for this cool community.